# How to update raster having x, y cells indices in R?

Tags: r, raster

I have exemplary raster:

```
r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
r[] = 0
r <- writeRaster(r, 'test.tif', overwrite=TRUE, datatype='INT2S')
```

And I need to update the last column of 10x10 grid except first and last square. So basically, it's what I want to apply:

```
update(r, rep(255, 10*10), dx=(91:100), dy=(11:90))
```

but there's no such parameters as `dx` and `dy` but `cell` parameter. How to recalculate it to have cells in stead of x, y indices?

Answer (score 1):

```
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=0)
```

You can do this instead of update

```
r[2:(nrow(r)-1), ncol(r)] <- 10
```

Or first compute cell numbers

```
cells <- cellFromRowCol(r, 2:(nrow(r)-1), ncol(r))
r[cells] <- 25
```

Or use the cell numbers with `update`

```
rr <- writeRaster(r, 'test.tif', overwrite=TRUE, datatype='INT2S')
# rr <- update(rr, rep(255, ncol(r)-2), cells)
rr <- update(rr, 255, cells)
```

Have a look

```
as.matrix(rr)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   255
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```